# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ConsoleUserInfoes_dbo.ConsolesCheckBoxes_consoleId"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ConsoleUserInfoes_dbo.ConsolesCheckBoxes_consoleId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-ForePlay-20180525122039", table "dbo.ConsolesCheckBoxes", column 'ConsoleId'.

I'm using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC 5 and `IdentityUser` and try to insert data form checkListBox to table into my database.

This is happening on the register view, when user need to register and fill the form.

```
public class ConsoleUserInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int identity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string userid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("consolesCheckBox")]
    public int consoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ConsolesCheckBox consolesCheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

This is the table that need to get a user id (form applictionUser) and consoleId
(form ConsolesCheckBox )

This is the ApplicationUserUser model class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    override
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public byte[] UserPhoto { get; set; }

    public virtual UserAddress Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConsolesCheckBox> consoleCheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the checkBoxList table:

```
public class ConsolesCheckBox
{
    [Key]
    public int ConsoleId { get; set; }

    public string ConsoleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

This is my account controller, all in the register get and post

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
        //using database
        using (ApplicationDbContext dbo = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            //data will save list of the consoleCheckBoxItem
            var data = dbo.consolesCheckBox.ToList();
            // because the view is request a common model, we will create new one
            CommenModel a = new CommenModel();
            a.ConsolesCheckBoxList = data;
            //  we will need to return common model, that way we will return a
            return View(a);
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Exclude = "UserPhoto")]CommenModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // To convert the user uploaded Photo as Byte Array before save to DB
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["UserPhoto"];

                using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);
                }
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.registerViewModel.Email,
                Email = model.registerViewModel.Email,
                Phone = model.registerViewModel.Phone
            };

            user.UserPhoto = imageData;
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.registerViewModel.Password);

            //after the user create, we will use the id and add the id to the userAddress table include
            // Address, longitude and latitude.
            using (ApplicationDbContext dbo = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var currentUserId = user.Id;
                var pasinfo = dbo.userAddress.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Userid == currentUserId);

                if (pasinfo == null)
                {
                    pasinfo = dbo.userAddress.Create();
                    pasinfo.Userid = currentUserId;
                    dbo.userAddress.Add(pasinfo);
                }

                pasinfo.Address = model.useraddress.Address;
                pasinfo.latitude = model.useraddress.latitude;
                pasinfo.longitude = model.useraddress.longitude;

                dbo.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var item in model.ConsolesCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ConsoleId))
                {
                    var consoleUserInfo = new ConsoleUserInfo
                    {
                        userid = currentUserId,
                        consoleId = item
                    };

                    dbo.consoleUserInfo.Add(consoleUserInfo);
                }

                dbo.SaveChanges();
            }
    }
}
```

In the register GET I have a common model, because I used 3 models in the view
this is the common model:

```
public class CommonModel
{
    public UserAddress useraddress { get; set; }
    public RegisterViewModel registerViewModel { get; set; }
    public List<ConsolesCheckBox> ConsolesCheckBoxList { get; set; }
}
```

I need your help here, I've been trying to fix this all day.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading.. It looks okay to me. Kinda hard to tell without a debugger in a situation like this (at least for me) I'd check the database schema if you never saw it working before to make sure the FK relationship is set properly.

Comment: @lloyd hey after debugging this row--> var item in model.ConsolesCheckBoxList.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ConsoleId) the is.Checked is true but the consoleid=0, in the table is id=1

Comment: So it sounds like that value is not getting passed back through the view if it's a 0? Make sure that gets passed properly.

Comment: hey, your right, in the view the hidden-for was for the console-name i changed this to console-id and its work!